How to prevent app installation in Android 15 Private Space?
Android 15's Private Space blocks push notifications when it is locked. In some apps, real-time push notifications are crucial. Is there a way to prevent app installation in Private Space to ensure that push notifications are not blocked?

Does this not ruin the point of Private Space?

Yes, but the other way round, if the final version of Private Space will block notifications, it will ruin the point of apps that rely on real-time notifications.

Wait what? I'm confused at the use case. Do you want users who install an app in Private Space to get notifications while not using Private Space? Or the other way around?

there are more use cases, like medical apps that need working and Private Space could interfere when blocked, like push notifications or killing the app/background process

Not only that! in fact we are hoping for an API that checks if the app run on "private space" or no, like it may be a Foreground/Background processes that I want to complete before the user exits the "private space" like showing a message (don't lock/exit this app during: download file / or banking processes for example, because you will lose your data).
